# bootstrap nav push-left / push-right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, alignment

I need to have one part of my horizontal menu/navigation floating left, and other floating right.

Like this:
**Option1_Option2____Option3_Option4_*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__Option5_Option6**

I am using this technique:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
  <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option4</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
  <li><a href="#">Option5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Option6</a></li>
</ul>
```

but since the floats are (has to be)`!important`I am having problems when the menu collapses on smaller (tablet/mobile) screen sizes.
It ends up being like this:

**Option1
Option2
Option3
Option4
  Option5
  Option6**

As you can see the two last needs to be floated to the left, so I have tried changing the `.pull-right {float: right !important;}` to `.pull-right {float: left !important;}` in the `@media` queries but no luck... I am stuck. Is there any way to over-ride`!important` in the @media queries, or any other way to address this issue?

Comment: Is your media query in a separate stylesheet or are you editing the bootstrap css?

Comment: You should be using only one `<ul>` for this, and adding the `pull-right` class to each `<li>` you want to float right

Comment: editing the bootstrap css..

Comment: thank you Bojangles, exept that nothing has really changed. same problem with the collapsed menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you wrapping your `ul`s in a `<div class="nav-collapse collapse">` ? your code seems to work just fine for me. See here -> [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/VNjYz/)

If you watch the computed styles of the `.pull-right` `ul` when collapsing the nav-bar you can see bootstrap changes the `float` from `right` to `none`.

This it directly from bootstrap.css....

```
@media (max-width: 979px)
  .navbar .nav-collapse .nav.pull-right {
      float: none;
      margin-left: 0;
   }
```

I am betting you have some conflicting CSS that is messing it up. Remove any custom `.pull-right` CSS you have, or any custom CSS for the entire navbar...

Comment: My macbook is on its 7th year and is doing some wierd stuff sometimes. I tried everything without success, so in the end I just had to start from scratch... delted everything, restarted computer and downloaded the BS fresh.. now it seems to work.

Comment: you forgot a couple of brackets

@media (max-width: 979px) {
  .navbar .nav-collapse .nav.pull-right {
      float: none;
      margin-left: 0;
   }
}